# CRM 2016 Web API, how can i auto forward emails from a queue?

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-webapi

I want to select specific emails, based on their subject and sender, from a queue, and then I need to forward these emails to another email address, including their attachments, and finally remove them from the queue I got them from.

How can I do this using the Web API ? I'm not having much luck figuring out Microsoft documentation at the moment.
I've gotten something out using the following URL but not sure this is the correct way to do it:

```
api/data/v8.1/queueitems?$filter=(_ownerid_value eq e27a264c-a4ea-e011-b87c-005056b543f3) and (startswith(title,'SearchTitle'))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is something like the Dynamics CRM 2011 ticketing project across teams queue, we did using Forward mailbox, mailbox rules & email router and pass it to right team queue using Plugin/Workflow.

Now since you want to achieve this in modern days (Server side sync), still you have to use the same **Email create Pre-operation plugin** & check your conditions from target entity. If that is met, you can create a new Email activity (Forward) or create a new Queueitem & assign the needed owner.

Not sure why you started with webapi query, if you want to automate this forward/assign logic - web api is not the way to search/filter because you cannot initiate this from nowhere by only having webapi result.